# ios 9 SKVIDEONODE Does it support Adaptive Bit Rate For Video?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avplayer, adaptive-bitrate

Does the SkVideoNode using AVPlayer support HLS Adaptive Bitrate for Video?

If so is there any way to limit or set the top and / or bottom rate?

Comment: Turns out that this looks like a bug in current ios 9.x.  Looking to see if can be added to ios 10

Comment: not fixed in iOS 10, no longer using SKVIDEONODE, now using CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage